# C++: usage of template for pointers with overloading arrow (->) operator

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, operator-overloading

I wrote this template class for pointers usage
(I need smart pointers, but I can't use boost or C++11):

```
template<class T>
class TreePointer{
public:
    TreePointer(){
        isRefOnly=false;  
        data=NULL;
    };
    TreePointer(T* data){
        this->data=data;
        this->isRefOnly=false;   
    }
    TreePointer(const TreePointer& anotherPtr){
        this->data=anotherPtr.data;
        this->isRefOnly=true;
    }
    virtual ~TreePointer(){
        if (!isRefOnly){                        
            delete data;
        }        
    }    
    T* operator->() const{
        return data;
    }
    void operator=(const TreePointer &anotherPtr){ 
        this->data=anotherPtr.data;
        this->isRefOnly=true;
    }        
private:
    T* data;
    bool isRefOnly;
};
```

And I have big class with many methods, like this:

```
class WrittenBigClassWithManyMethods{
public:
    WrittenBigClassWithManyMethods(int v){
        this->v=v;
    }    
    int sum(WrittenBigClassWithManyMethods* a){
        return v+a->v;
    }
    int v;
};
```

This usage of my smart pointers work perfectly:

```
TreePointer<WrittenBigClassWithManyMethods> tp(new WrittenBigClassWithManyMethods(5));
WrittenBigClassWithManyMethods* simpleClass=new WrittenBigClassWithManyMethods(5);
cout << tp->sum(simpleClass);
```

But it usage isn't work:

```
TreePointer<WrittenBigClassWithManyMethods> tp2(new WrittenBigClassWithManyMethods(5));
cout << tp->sum(tp2);
```

How i can change my template for pointers to make invoking methrod **sum** of class **WrittenBigClassWithManyMethods** with parameter of type **TreePointer**, without any changes for class **WrittenBigClassWithManyMethods** and its any usages? If this is not possible, how I minimize the changes for class **WrittenBigClassWithManyMethods** and its usage?

Comment: `TreePointer p = makeThingy();` probably won't behave how you want it to.  This isn't a smart pointer, it's a mix of unique_ptr and raw pointers, depending on the boolean state. Instead, just use unique_ptr, and T&.

Comment: Or just use `std::auto_ptr`, which isn't C++11.

Answer (score 2):

Usually you'll want to overload the unary operator * (de-reference) too, returning a `T&`. Then you can have both a reference and the original pointer by taking the address of the result:

```
tp1->method_that_takes_ref(*tp2); // With operator*()
tp1->method_that_takes_ptr(&*tp2); // Works, but syntax might be a bit surprising
```

Another way to get at the pointer inside would be to call `operator ->` directly, but that would be a bit awkward. You are likely better off providing some kind of "get" method, like the one in unique_ptr, that simply returns the raw pointer:

```
tp1->method_that_takes_ptr(tp2.operator->()); // Works, but ugh
tp1->method_that_takes_ptr(tp2.get()); // Much clearer
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a conversion operator to `T*`:

```
operator T*() {
    return data;
}
```

Now the compiler will call it whenever it wants to convert a `TreePointer<SomeClass>` to a `SomeClass*`.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that, by the virtue of implicit conversions, it allows you to use pointer arithmetic on your smart pointer object directly, which usually does not make sense in that context. That is why unique_ptr does not offer such an operator, and instead provides a "get" member function.